# Grub2 cannot see cloned ubuntu install

Tags: grub2

Ive cloned my ubuntu installation, but cannot get grub2 to see it.

Before I had the install on /dev/sda1 and a grub boot prtition on /dev/sda2

I copied them both to a new disk - now boot prtition is on /sdb1 and the cloned partition (using gparted) is on /sdb2

Ive set the BIOS boot order ot boot from the driv ive copied to. At startup the first time it booted into the old install (this was expected, since I hadnt changed the grub entries)

But now, while in my 'old' installation, if I run grub-mkconfig it only finds the install on /dev/sda1, and not its copy on /dev/sdb2

Ive tried reinstalling grub from scratch but no joy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the cloned partitions new UUIDs so they are not confused with the old ones.  Run `sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1`.