# Cloned disk refuses to boot

Tags: partitioning, dd, cloning

I have a Ubuntu box which is currently running on an old 500GB HDD.

As I got hold of a 240GB SSD and the HDD was only used partially (10% used) I decided to clone the HDD to the SSD.

Since the HDD is larger then the SSD, I defragmented it and resized its data partition to a size under 240GB. After this the system is still working and boots up as usual.

[image: Here is the new HDD geometry as reported by gparted.]

Since the SSD was on a 100% Windows machine it had a `MBR` partition table which I replaced with a `gpt` partition table. I then created two partitions of the same size as the ones present in the HDD.

[image: Here is the SDD geometry as reported by gparted.]

I then started the PC using another Ubuntu bootable USB and issued these two `dd` commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdd1 status=progress
sudo dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/dev/sdd2 status=progress
```

All went fine without errors but at the end of it the PC refuses to boot from the SDD.

Partition /dev/sdd2 seems to have been correctly cloned since I can mount it when I either boot from /dev/sda or from the bootable USB. But I notice that the used space in /dev/sda2 is larger then the used space in /dev/sdd2. I suspect this is due to any temporary files and devices resulting from booting from it.

I tried to boot from the SSD without any other disks connected but all I get is that when the PC is booting it goes straight into the BIOS/EFI menu.

Any idea why my SSD refuses to start?

Comment: Thanks @mook765 but isn’t the dd of /dev/sda1 to /dev/sdd1 supposed to copy the boot partition as it is right now?

Comment: The MBR is not a partition at all, you need to install an instance of grub into the MBR of the new drive to make the drive bootable in legacy mode.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll look into that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grub2 cannot see cloned ubuntu install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97971/grub2-cannot-see-cloned-ubuntu-install)

Comment: When you clone just a partition with dd, only the partition gets cloned. The bootloader does not get cloned. You can clone the full disc and then truncate the results to put them on a smaller drive, See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1300542/43926

Comment: or At this point it is probably easiest to just reinstall GRUB. booted in BIOS mode run:   `sudo mount /dev/sdx3 /mnt`     
   `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx`

Comment: grub-install was giving me a funky error so I ended up using boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @Fabricio It sounds like you resolved this.  If so, please add your solution as an answer and mark it accepted so that this gets closed out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying individual partitions was necessary to clone the original disk since the target disk was smaller than the original one. However following a couple of comments I eventually realized that copying individual partitions wouldn't copy the boot record.

To resolve this issue I eventually used the application Boot-Repair ([help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair))

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced an Ubuntu no boot issue after cloning my dual boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04) from my HDD to a new M.2 NVMe SSD.
Windows was booting fine but Ubuntu was just showing the Grub shell.

As recommended here and in some other forums too I used the Ubuntu Boot-Info tool which showed the issue was, during cloning GRUB was installed in partition1 instead of partition7 where my Ubuntu installation was.
So I used Ubuntu Boot-Repair tool which reinstalled GRUB in the correct partition and voila!  My Ubuntu was back in business and Grub loaded working as before

Boot-Info :

- Diagnostics before repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rWsrWKXx8N/
- Diagnostics after repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pw3WnTcFDv/

[Boot-Repair screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XofWm.jpg)